# Resize image with jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize an Image with jQuery  **'live'** (not to save it).
so. I have the wrapper div with a `width x height` of `1328 x 638`

> I want to: make the image `width 100%` if the image width is
>   bigger than `height`
>
> and the height 100% if the image height is bigger than `width`

I made some codes but not working

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
var src    = $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').attr('src');
tmpImg.src = src;
$(tmpImg).one('load',function(){
  orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
  orgHeight = tmpImg.height;

  if(orgWidth > orgHeight)
  {
      $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"width":"100%"});
      }
      else if(orgWidth < orgHeight)
      {
          $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"heigh":"100%"});
          }
          else
          {
              $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"heigh":"100%"});
              }
    });
```

Comment: it's `height` actually, not `heigh` -> `{"height":"100%"}`

Comment: yeah :D my bad I was angry :p thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tmpImg = new Image();
        var src    = $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').attr('src');
        tmpImg.src = src;
        $(tmpImg).on('load',function(){
          orgWidth = tmpImg.width;
          orgHeight = tmpImg.height;
          if(orgWidth > orgHeight) {
                  $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"width":"100%"});
              }
              else if(orgWidth < orgHeight) {
                  $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"height":"100%"});
              }
              else {
                 $('#ImageOverlay table tr td img').css({"height":"100%"});
              }
            });
```

you also had a typo in `$(tmpImg).one..` -> `$(tmpImg).on..`

Comment: still the same problem :/

Comment: well, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: the image still not fit to the div, if an image with `1920px` is loaded in the `td` it will be fit using `$('selector').css({"width":"100%"});`